# glDrawArrays is bound to single texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I have a number of textures loaded using GLKTextureLoader. If I bind any of the loaded textures statically, each texture works as expected.

But I am trying to bind a random texture each glDrawArrays call, but the texture bound is always the same.

```
GLuint vbo =  vboIDs[emitterNum];

GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeScale(1.0f, aspectRatio, 1.0f);

glUseProgram(emitterShader[emitterNum].program);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE0);
//Note: valid texture names are 0-31, but in my code I store texture names returned in an array and use them. Use arc4random here for simplicity
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, arc4random_uniform(31)); //use a random texture name
//glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2); //If I use this line instead of the line above, it will draw texture 2, or any number I specify

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

glUniformMatrix4fv(emitterShader[emitterNum].uProjectionMatrix, 1, 0, projectionMatrix.m);

//I set a number of uniforms such as:
glUniform1f(emitterShader[emitterNum].uTime, timeCurrentFrame);
glUniform1i(emitterShader[emitterNum].uTexture, 0);

//I set a number of vertex arrays such as:
glEnableVertexAttribArray(emitterShader[emitterNum].aShade);
glVertexAttribPointer(emitterShader[emitterNum].aShade,                // Set pointer
                      4,                                        // four components per particle (vec4)
                      GL_FLOAT,                                 // Data is floating point type
                      GL_FALSE,                                 // No fixed point scaling
                      sizeof(Particles),                        // No gaps in data
                      (void*)(offsetof(Particles, shade)));     // Start from "shade" offset within bound buffer

GLsizei rowsToUse = emitters[emitterNum]->rows;

//Draw the arrays
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, rowsToUse );

//Then clean up
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glUseProgram(0);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

I have tried putting the texture calls in various places, like where shown and direct before the glDrawArrays command, but no matter what - I can't make it bind to different textures unless done so statically.

Comment: `arc4random_uniform(31)` You claim that this retrieves a random texture. Does it really?

Comment: 1. You have a variable called _vbo_ and a vboList but you are clearly refering to it as a vertex array, i.e. a _vao_ 2. if you actually are talking about a vao then your _glBindBuffer_ is wrong, it should be _glBindVertexArray_ 3. You should set the vertex attributes once, when creating the vao, _not_ every frame

Comment: Plus, like @NicolBolas said, is `arc4random_uniform(31)` actually providing _valid_ texture names?

Comment: Yes, it arc4random is providing valid texture names. In my code I use an array to store the texture names, but they are number from 0-31, and was trying the simplest way possible.

Comment: @itzJanuary: "*you are clearly refering to it as a vertex array, i.e. a vao*" No, he's not. He's using `vbo` exactly like one would use a buffer object, not like one would use a VAO. No version of OpenGL ES, to my knowledge, requires the use of VAOs.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock A texture name is the thing returned by `glGenTextures`. Did `glGenTextures` return the numbers 0 to 31?

Comment: Setting the vertex arrays every frame is the only way I have been able to get the code to draw (everything is exactly as I want it if I could just use more than one texture). Not sure why - but I am also rendering to an offscreen buffer.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock Sorry my bad. Gotta love OpenGL for its names!

Comment: @immibis the texture names are returned in a GLKTextureInfo structure from GLKTextureLoader and are indeed 0-31.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock I know that's not true, because [0 is not a valid texture name](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Objects#Object_zero).

Comment: @immibis Well that is what is returned from GLKTextureLoader. I can post the list of output above - but it is literally just a list of 0 to 31 for the texture names.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock That is indeed weird and definitely should not happen